# serde_json - how to make my struct convertable from / to json?

Tags: json, rust, serde

Looking at [the documentation of serde_json](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde_json/serde_json/index.html), I can't understand what trait I have to implement to make a struct serializiable to and deserializiable from json. The obvious answer could be [`Deserializer`](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde_json/serde_json/de/struct.Deserializer.html) and [`Serializer`](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde_json/serde_json/ser/struct.Serializer.html) but these are structs, not traits.

With `rustc-serialize` I could implement `ToJson` and `FromJson` traits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [crate index page](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.61/serde_json/):

> Serde provides a mechanism for low boilerplate serialization & deserialization of values to and from JSON via the serialization API. To be able to serialize a piece of data, it must implement the [`serde::Serialize`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.119/serde/trait.Serialize.html) trait. To be able to deserialize a piece of data, it must implement the [`serde::Deserialize`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.119/serde/trait.Deserialize.html) trait. Serde provides provides an annotation to automatically generate the code for these traits: `#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]`.

-- [Creating Json by Serializing Data Structures](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.61/serde_json/#creating-json-by-serializing-data-structures)

Comment: it doesn't have the link to serde::Serialize, where did you get it?

Comment: @jawanam It's defined in the `serde` crate here https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde/serde/index.html

Comment: It is, but it's not given in the documentation.

Comment: @jawanam Yeah, I was confused a bit where they were defined too.

Answer (score 2):

To deserialize a struct into a json file run a code similar to the following one :

```rust
let struct = Struct::create();
let slice_string_in_json_format = serde_json::to_string(&struct);
```

Instead to serielize a json file component into a struct you can use a similar pattern:

```rust
fn parsing_json_into_struct() -> Result<Struct> {

    // Open the json file
    let mut file_content = match File::open("file.json") {
        Ok(
            file) => file,  
            Err(_) => panic!("Could not read the json file")
    };

    // Transform content of the file into a string 
    let mut contents = String::new();
    match file_content.read_to_string(&mut contents)
     {
        Ok(_) => {},
        Err(err) => panic!("Could not deserialize the file, error code: {}", err)
    };

    let module: Result<Struct> = serde_json::from_str(&contents.as_str());
    module
}
```